# I am having trouble running my csv file through my code and I don't understand the error message

Tags: python, pandas, csv

I am trying to run a csv file through my code and work with the data. I am receiving a error message that I don't exactly understand.

[Here is the csv file](https://i.stack.imgur.com/DBSCh.png)

There is a lot more code but I will only include code that is relevant to the problem. Comment below if you need more info.

```
import pandas as pd
df_playoffs = pd.read_csv('/Users/hannahbeegle/Desktop/playoff_teams.csv.numbers', encoding='latin-1', index_col = 'team')
df_playoffs.fillna('None', inplace=True)
```

Here is the error message:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/Users/hannahbeegle/Desktop/Baseball.py", line 130, in <module>
    df_playoffs = pd.read_csv('/Users/hannahbeegle/Desktop/playoff_teams.csv.numbers', encoding='latin-1', index_col = 'team')
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.7/lib/python3.7/site-packages/pandas/io/parsers.py", line 702, in parser_f
    return _read(filepath_or_buffer, kwds)
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.7/lib/python3.7/site-packages/pandas/io/parsers.py", line 435, in _read
    data = parser.read(nrows)
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.7/lib/python3.7/site-packages/pandas/io/parsers.py", line 1139, in read
    ret = self._engine.read(nrows)
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.7/lib/python3.7/site-packages/pandas/io/parsers.py", line 1995, in read
    data = self._reader.read(nrows)
  File "pandas/_libs/parsers.pyx", line 899, in pandas._libs.parsers.TextReader.read
  File "pandas/_libs/parsers.pyx", line 914, in pandas._libs.parsers.TextReader._read_low_memory
  File "pandas/_libs/parsers.pyx", line 968, in pandas._libs.parsers.TextReader._read_rows
  File "pandas/_libs/parsers.pyx", line 955, in pandas._libs.parsers.TextReader._tokenize_rows
  File "pandas/_libs/parsers.pyx", line 2172, in pandas._libs.parsers.raise_parser_error
pandas.errors.ParserError: Error tokenizing data. C error: Expected 1 fields in line 3, saw 2
```

Comment: There is no CSV data, there is only a picture of some rendering of your CSV data. According to the error there's a problem with the number of fields in line 3 of your CSV file.

Comment: Try using  `pd.read_csv('/Users/hannahbeegle/Desktop/playoff_teams.csv.numbers', encoding='latin-1', index_col = 'team', sep='\s\s+')` or `sep='\t'`

Comment: Judging from the picture of the rendering of your CSV file, each row has a different number of columns associated with it, which is not good if you're trying to put the data in a *rectangular* data frame. I'm not sure if that is due to some NaNs in the file not appearing in the rendering, though.

Comment: @ScottBoston this is the end of the error message: ParserError: Expected 2 fields in line 484, saw 3. Error could possibly be due to quotes being ignored when a multi-char delimiter is used.

Comment: I would look at line 484 of your csv and see what is different about that line versus the ones above it.

Comment: @ScottBoston I don't have 484 lines of my csv file it's one for every MLB team so it's only 30 lines

Comment: Paste a link to yoyr csv file.

Comment: @ScottBoston you can see my csv file above

Comment: @Hannah, what you posted cannot be a CSV file because it has no commas! It's just a table rendered in some GUI application, rather than the text of the actual file.

Answer (score 0):

Looks as though your csv is maybe tab delimited, in the line that specifies the csv, edit to something like:

```
pd.read_csv('/Users/hannahbeegle/Desktop/playoff_teams.csv.numbers', sep="\t", encoding='latin-1', index_col = 'team')
```

[edited section after comments]

If the data is "ragged" then you could try breaking it up into a dictionary, and then using that to build the dataframe - here's an example I tried with a mocked-up sample dataset:

```
record_dict = {}
file=open("variable_columns.csv", mode="r")
for line in file.readlines():
    split_line = line.split()
    record_dict[split_line[0]]=split_line[1:]
df_playoffs = pd.DataFrame.from_dict(record_dict, orient='index' )

df_playoffs.sample(5)
```

[image]

You might need to look at the `line.split()` line, and enter `"\t"` as the split parameter (i.e. `line.split("\t")` but you can experiment with this.

Also, notice that pandas has forced the data to be rectangular, so some of the columns will contain `None` for the "short" rows.

Comment: when I did, this the error message was the same except for the last line says: Expected 1 fields in line 3, saw 3

Comment: Ahh ok, so it looks as though your csv file doesn't conform to the usual layout - the normal expectation is for these files to contain the same number of columns for each row. When pandas tries to read one of these files, it uses the first row to give it a clue as to how many columns to expect for the rest of the file - and because your file has different numbers of columns, it's upsetting the load process.

Comment: So how do I fix that?

Comment: If i put in the command: print(df_playoffs.sample(5))
I want it to look like this:
team                                                                
NYM   1969, 1973, 1986, 1988, 1999, 2000, 2006, 2015...   1969, 1986
HOU   1980, 1981, 1986, 1997, 1998, 1999, 2001, 2004...         2017
CHC   1906, 1907, 1908, 1910, 1918, 1929, 1932, 1935...         2016
WSA                                                None         None
DET   1907, 1908, 1909, 1934, 1935, 1940, 1945, 1968...         1984

Comment: Take a look at the edit, I've used pretend data that I've mocked up, so it's ABC, DEF instead of your HOU, WSA etc - but the method ought to work on your data if it's in a similar layout.